# How can I Insert data into SQL Server using VBNet

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am new to `vb.net` I need to insert  data in table by using vb.net please can any one help

I have tried this

Here I tried Sample Code

I got this exception `Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`
thanks advance

```vb
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs)  Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim strName As String = txtName.Text
    Dim strId As String = txtID.Text
    Dim strPhone As String = txtPhone.Text
    Dim strBranch As String = cmboxBranch.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim  strCourse As String = cmbboxCourse.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim dblFee As Double = Double.Parse(txtFee.Text) 

    Dim strCommand As String = "insert into student values('" & strName & "','" & strId &    "','" & strPhone & "','" & strBranch & "','" & strCourse & "'," & dblFee & ")"

    Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strCommand, connection)
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text

    '' MsgBox(strCommand) 

    connection.Open()
    If (command.ExecuteNonQuery().Equals(1)) Then
        MsgBox("Information stored in database")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not stored in database")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You should show us the _table definition_. Maybe you've forgotten to make the pk column `IDENTITY`with autoincrement. Btw, you're open for SQL-Injection. You should use [`SqlParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

Comment: my table `defn` is  `student(SName,SID,SPhone,SBranch,SCourse,SFee)`
all are belong to `varchar` type except `fee` (`fee is real type`)

Comment: @rangasathish - that's not a table definition. Easiest is to go to the table using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). Right click it, choose "Script Table -> As Create -> To Clipboard". Then *edit* your question and paste in the result. It will show us the *data types* for the table, any *constraints*, etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It means that the number of values specified in your `VALUES` clause on the `INSERT` statement is not equal to the total number of columns in the table. You must specify the columnname if you only try to insert on selected columns.

Another one, since you are using `ADO.Net` , always parameterized your query to avoid `SQL Injection`. What you are doing right now is you are *defeating* the use of `sqlCommand`.

ex

```vb
Dim query as String = String.Empty
query &= "INSERT INTO student (colName, colID, colPhone, "
query &= "                     colBranch, colCourse, coldblFee)  "
query &= "VALUES (@colName,@colID, @colPhone, @colBranch,@colCourse, @coldblFee)"

Using conn as New SqlConnection("connectionStringHere")
    Using comm As New SqlCommand()
        With comm
            .Connection = conn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = query
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colName", strName)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colID", strId)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colPhone", strPhone)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colBranch", strBranch)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@colCourse", strCourse)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@coldblFee", dblFee)
        End With
        Try
            conn.open()
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch(ex as SqlException)
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error Message")
        End Try
    End Using
End USing
```

***PS: Please change the column names specified in the query to the original column found in your table.***

Comment: Side-note: the `conn.Close` is redundant since you're using `using-statement` anyway.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks for reminding :) but i used to do that. Anyway, I just update my answer.

Comment: I would vote +2 if I could for the promotion of parametrized queries

Comment: @JohnWoo: Anyway, +1 because of using parameters,using-statement,error-handling and one possible reason for the error.

Comment: You might also want to mention  that `'Error here'` should be replaced with appropriate [error handling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET)(f.e. logging). Don't ever [swallow exceptions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET#Don%27teverswallowexceptions13).

Comment: @JohnWoo & Tim  - I am trying to something similar with a few add ons and I am using this example but am unable to get it working could you maybe have a look at this please :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909078/how-to-get-an-e-command-from-a-grid-in-asp-net-to-update-an-order-table?noredirect=1#comment63270892_37909078

Comment: No point creating a new post for this; by changing the sqlconnections to OLEDBCommands - would this work for Microsoft Access?

Comment: In case anyone is not aware: [AddWithValue is Evil](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [AddWithValue is evil!](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), and [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Imports System.Data

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form2

Dim myconnection As SqlConnection

Dim mycommand As SqlCommand

Dim dr As SqlDataReader

Dim dr1 As SqlDataReader

Dim ra As Integer


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


    myconnection = New SqlConnection("server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=;database=simple")

    'you need to provide password for sql server

    myconnection.Open()

    mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into tbl_cus([name],[class],[phone],[address]) values ('" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox3.Text & "','" & TextBox4.Text & "')", myconnection)

    mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("New Row Inserted" & ra)

    myconnection.Close()

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: ⚠️ Do not use. Insecure / poor SQL coding practice.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function ExtSql(ByVal sql As String) As Boolean
    Dim cnn As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand
    cnn = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.mySqlConnectionString)
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = cnn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cnn.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception
        cnn.Close()
        Return False
    End Try
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: Please, consider adding a bit more detail and explanation to your code.