# INSERT INTO SELECT using vb.net Can't Insert

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, select, insert

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Con.Open()
    Dim Str As String = "INSERT INTO db (ID,companyname,companyaddress,companycontact,contactperson,contactnumber,UserLogin,mDate) SELECT @ID,@companyname,@companyaddress,@companycontact,@contactperson,@contactnumber,@UserLogin,@mDate FROM db WHERE Userlogin = @Userlogin"

    Dim Cmd As New OleDbCommand
    With Cmd

        .CommandText = Str

        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", f1.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", f2.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyaddress", f3.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@companycontact", f4.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactperson", f5.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactnumber", f6.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLogin", f12.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@mDate", DateTimePicker1.Text)
        .Connection = Con

        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
    If Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
        Con.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("New Record is Added successfully.", "Record Saved")
        Call clear()

    Else

        MsgBox("Could Not Insert Record!!! ", "Already Entered")
        Return
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please add some context to explain the code.

Comment: Are there any errors? I would look at using `.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType).Value =` and explicitly set each `SqlDataType`.

Comment: i got a solution for this thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You must pass the date *value*:

```
.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors when calling the ExecuteNonQuery() method?
I checked your code and I have two comments:
(1) You are calling the ExecuteNonQuery() twice in your code:
+------------------------+
'First call
.ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
'Second call
If Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
+------------------------+
Are you calling the method twice on purpose?
2. Make sure that the connection is opened before calling the Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() method.

If you are still facing problems, I found a related issue here with some valuable information:
[How can I Insert data into SQL Server using VBNet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634516/how-can-i-insert-data-into-sql-server-using-vbnet)

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I don't unterstand why you are using the SELECT? I think you want to do this:

INSERT INTO db(ID,companyname,companyaddress,companycontact,contactperson,contactnumber,UserLogin,mDate) VALUES (@ID,@companyname,@companyaddress,@companycontact,@contactperson,@contactnumber,@UserLogin,@mDate)

Comment: For duplication purposes so that is why im trying to use insert into select to avoid double entry

Comment: To avoid this, try REPLACE INTO instead of INSERT INTO. If the primary key exists, MySQL will first delete this row and then do a normal insert.

Comment: it says Invalid SQL Statement

Comment: OK, I thought, you are using MySQL. For MSSQL add a DELETE in front of the INSERT using your primary key (@id I think), like this:
DELETE FROM db WHERE ID=@ID;
INSERT INTO db(ID,companyname,companyaddress,companycontact,contactperson,contactnumber,UserLogin,mDate) VALUES (@ID,@companyname,@companyaddress,@companycontact,@contactperson,@contactnumber,@UserLogin,@mDate)

Comment: im using ms access 2010

Comment: got it already i used this INSERT INTO db(ID,companyname,companyaddress,companycontact,contactperson,contactnumber,UserLogin,mDate) 
  SELECT @ID,@companyname,@companyaddress,@companycontact,@contactperson,@contactnumber,@UserLogin,@mDate 
  FROM DB AS X 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT companyname FROM db as Y WHERE Y.ID = @ID)