# IF adding record is cancelled then return adding another record

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Im having a problem of adding records when I click the messagebox and i answered is no then cancel it and add another record but im having a message of connection has not been initialized heres my code thank you.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        conn.Open()
        Dim bday As String
        bday = adyear.Text & "-" & admonth.Text & "-" & adday.Text


        If adfirstname.Text.Length < 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Firstname is too short")
        End If

        Dim exist As String
        exist = "select * from record where firstname='" & adfirstname.Text & "'" & " and lastname='" & adlastname.Text & "';"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(exist, conn)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If reader.HasRows = True Then
            If MsgBox("THE MEMBER YOU ARE TRYING TO ADD HAS AN SAME FIRSTNAME AND LASTNAME IN THE RECORD DO YOU WISH TO CONTINUE ?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            ElseIf adage.Text < 18 Then
                If MsgBox("The member is less than 18 years old is this an intern?", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                    Dim add As String
                    add = "insert into record(firstname,middlename,lastname,birthday,age,jobposition)" & _
                         "values(" & _
                         "'" & adfirstname.Text & "'," & _
                         "'" & admiddlename.Text & "'," & _
                         "'" & adlastname.Text & "'," & _
                         "'" & bday & "'," & _
                         "'" & adage.Text & "'," & _
                         "'" & adjobposition.Text & "');"
                    cmd = New SqlCommand(add, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MessageBox.Show("Added Complete")

                Else
                    MsgBox("Action is Terminated")

                    ' code for return to adding and stop the messagebox of the connection has not been initialized


                End If
            End If
        End If

            conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: [Bobby Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) are all around you

Comment: what's a bobby tables?

Comment: Concatenating strings in the way you do to build your sql command is well known to be a great security risk and simple target for hackers. The Bobby Tables is the child made famous from the comic strip linked above.

Comment: can you help with the proper way of adding records? I thought concatenating strings in querying a table is the proper way of inserting record

Comment: Too broad. [You can read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634516/how-can-i-insert-data-into-sql-server-using-vbnet) where there is an answer with a proper way to add a record to a database in vb.net. Also you have logical errors in your code. If there are no rows you don't insert a new record? And if you press yes to your first question (Yes I want to continue) you do nothing? I suggest you to remove temporarily all these conditions and do a straight insert. Then one by one reinsert your conditions and check if the code still works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since it appears the conn is a form level object you would need to call

```
conn = New SqlConnection(<connection string>)
```

before you can use it to open the connection.  Given that you call

```
conn.Dispose()
```

to destroy the conn instance in the Finally block it appears that you do not keep an open connection around for long.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand im new in programming.

Comment: You are getting an error message that the connection has not been initialized.  So before you call conn.Open you need to create a new instance of conn....like I showed you in the code above.   If you are new to programming where did you get the code you posted?

Comment: its mine i just dont know how to find a solution in  connection has not been initialized