# How to Enter 3 Textbox value into one fieldname

Tags: vb.net

This is my Code I want to Enter First_Name,Middle_name and Last_Name in one Fieldname

```
    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "INSERT INTO residentrecords.info (id,last_name,first_name,middle_name,age,address,contact_no,date_of_birth,religion,civil_status,education_attainment,occupation,fathers_name,mothers_name,mothers_occupation,fathers_occupation,gender,purok,blotter,docu,voter) values ('" & add.TextBox_ID.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_LN.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_FN.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_MN.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_Age.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_Address.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_Contact.Text & "','" & add.DateTimePicker1.Text & "','" & add.ComboBox_religion.Text & "','" & add.ComboBox_CS.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_Educ.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_Occu.Text & "','" & add.TextBox1_FathersName.Text & "','" & add.TextBox1_MothersName.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_mothersocc.Text & "','" & add.TextBox_fathersocc.Text & "','" & add.ComboBox_gender.Text & "','" & add.rpurok.Text & "','0','0','" & add.voter.Text & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Registered!", "REGISTERED", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None)
        If vbOK = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
            Me.Dispose()
            add.Dispose()
            add.Enabled = True
            residents.Show()
        End If
        MysqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Your DB appears to have columns for each of those so why do you want to concatenate them?  However that is not the correct way to create SQL.  Use DB Parameters and also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634626/880990

Comment: Hello Olivier thanks for answering can you tell what is this? https://prnt.sc/hcwlvt

Comment: This line `Query = "INSERT INTO residentrecords.info ... ` is a nightmare. Parameterize your query and break the insert statement into multiple lines in vb. If it's difficult to see your code in a SO question, it must be equally painful in your IDE.

Comment: thanks guys for telling me to change to parameters thats all I need thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's quite easy in .net. You need to split one string on it's whitespaces and insert the substrings seperately.

Use somethiing like this

```
Dim names as String()
Dim firstName as String
Dim middleName as String
Dim lastName as String

names = add.TextBox_Name.Text.Split(" ")

firstName = names(0)
middleName = names(1)
lastName = names(2)
```

You might check the array length by forehand to make sure the user really has a middle name. Or even more than one. I have two. Just check for `names.length`.

I hope i didn't misinterpreted your question. It was quite short explained.