# I want to copy my JSON data to a SQL table using VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net

I have data in JSON file and I want to copy it to a SQL table.

Here is my JSON file data:

```
{
  "SuccessResponse": {
    "Head": {
      "RequestId": "A1",
      "RequestAction": "GetBrands",
      "ResponseType": "Brands",
      "Timestamp": "2019-09-23T22:43:08-05:00"
    },
    "Body": {
      "Brands": [
        {
          "BrandId": 23885,
          "Name": "Brand 1",
          "GlobalIdentifier": "B1"
        },
        {
          "BrandId": 23886,
          "Name": "Brand 2",
          "GlobalIdentifier": "B2"
        },
        {
          "BrandId": 23887,
          "Name": "Brand 3",
          "GlobalIdentifier": "B3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have figured out how to extract the data using an array, but I want to copy all the data records in the above JSON file to a SQL table.

```
Dim x As String = "{'products':[{'title':'Mouse','price':'20$'},{'title':'KeyBoard','price':'30$'}]}"
Dim result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(x)

Console.WriteLine(result("products")(0)("title") & " - " & result("products")(0)("price"))
Console.WriteLine(result("products")(1)("title") & " - " & result("products")(1)("price"))
```

I got the following result from the above code:

```
Mouse - 20$
KeyBoard - 30$
```

But I need a result like this:
[image: desired result]

Comment: Please edit the question instead of adding comments.

Comment: You can check the solution posted in this question 
 : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634516/how-can-i-insert-data-into-sql-server-using-vbnet .

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, the thread you shared is of saving data into Sql but I want my JSON file data to be desalinized and copied to SQL database..

Comment: @SajidSoomro What is the difference between "saving data into Sql " and "copied to SQL database"?

Comment: @Mary There is no difference at all, but I need my program to convert data which in JSON script and save it to database fields.

Answer (score 0):

I save a file with your the json you provided. It is called Sajid.json and is in my bin/Debug directory.

The classes I used are as follows. Close to what is used by .PasteSpecial but I like lists better than arrays.

```vb
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property SuccessResponse As Successresponse
End Class

Public Class Successresponse
    Public Property Head As Head
    Public Property Body As Body
End Class

Public Class Head
    Public Property RequestId As String
    Public Property RequestAction As String
    Public Property ResponseType As String
    Public Property Timestamp As Date
End Class

Public Class Body
    Public Property Brands As List(Of Brand)
End Class

Public Class Brand
    Public Property BrandId As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property GlobalIdentifier As String
End Class
```

In the button code the json string is deserialized into the classes. The command is created with parameters.

The parameters are added to the command with the value set for those that are the same for each insert. I had to guess at the datatypes and field sizes. You will need to check your database for the actual types and sizes.

The parameters whose values change are added outside the loop and only the values are changed inside the loop.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim s As String = File.ReadAllText("sajid.json")
    Dim myJs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(s)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Insert Into SomeTable (RequestID, RequestAction, ResposeType, TimeStamp, Brands_BrandId, Brands_Name, Brands_GlobalIdentifier)
          Values (@RequestID, @RequestAction, @ResposeType, @TimeStamp, @Brands_BrandId, @Brands_Name, @Brands_GlobalIdentifier);", cn)
            With cmd.Parameters
                .Add("@RequestID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = myJs.SuccessResponse.Head.RequestId
                .Add("@RequestAction", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = myJs.SuccessResponse.Head.RequestId
                .Add("@ResposeType", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = myJs.SuccessResponse.Head.ResponseType
                .Add("@TimeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = myJs.SuccessResponse.Head.Timestamp
                .Add("@Brands_BrandId", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
                .Add("@Brands_Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
                .Add("@Brands_GlobalIdentifier", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10)
            End With
            Dim bList = myJs.SuccessResponse.Body.Brands
            cn.Open()
            For Each b In bList
                cmd.Parameters("@Brands_BrandId").Value = b.BrandId
                cmd.Parameters("@Brands_Name").Value = b.Name
                cmd.Parameters("Brands_GlobalIdentifier").Value = b.GlobalIdentifier
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works like charm, Thanks.

There was a little typo near

```
    cmd.Parameters("Brands_GlobalIdentifier").Value = b.GlobalIdentifier
```

I have corrected it by adding @ Sign Before Brands_GlobalIdentifier Parameter

```
    cmd.Parameters("@Brands_GlobalIdentifier").Value = b.GlobalIdentifier
```