# VB.NET insert data via form

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to insert data to database, but getting error as `ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.`

Everything seems ok with the connection.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class crud1
    Private Sub Add_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Add_btn.Click
        Try
            Dim conn_ As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-VVM5A31;Initial Catalog=temp;Integrated Security=True")
            conn_.Open()
            Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO STUDENT (student_name, student_age) VALUES (@NAME, @AGE)")
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TXT_NAME.Text)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AGE", Convert.ToInt32(TXT_AGE.Text))
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            conn_.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Please see the image for the connection property.

[image]

Comment: You never attach your connection `conn_` to your SqlCommand `command` to; as such you get an error that the connection wasn't initialised, as `command.Connection` hasn't been set. Ideally you should be using `Using` syntax too. See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12634626/2029983).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right taking into account that the command needs the connection open, before execute the command, and you are doing right.

But you are not telling to the command which is the connection to be used.

An easy way to do it would be something like this, before execute the command:

```
command.Connection = conn_
```

Comment: That's not wrong but, under the circumstances, it would make more sense to pass the connection to the command constructor: `Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO STUDENT (student_name, student_age) VALUES (@NAME, @AGE)", conn_)`.