# SQL query to add row in a table - insert a value stored in another variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, ssms

Context, part of code extracted:

```
 Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
        mySqlConnection.Open()
        Dim newCourseName As String = InputBox("Type the name of the course you want to create", "Create new course")
        While newCourseName = "" Or ListBox1.Items.Contains(newCourseName) Or newCourseName.Length > 15
            newCourseName = InputBox("Invalid name! Type the name of the course you want to create (max 15 char)", "Create new course")
        End While

        mySqlCommand.Connection = mySqlConnection.ReturnConnection()
        mySqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = "**SQL QUERY HERE: Query that adds the new course to the table. Name is found in the variable newCourseName**."

        mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        mySqlConnection.Close()
        UpdateList()
    End Sub
```

Important disclaimer that I am new to this.
Code is part of a larger collection of classes that show a console where typing in things like CourseName when creating one would then go through the part of code shown above, connected to a few other things which I hope are not relevant to adding further context to my question.

The purpose is to simply writing practice queries, so the only part of code that is to be changed is the "SQL QUERY HERE: " part. Would `INSERT INTO tableName (CourseName) VALUES (_)` be used here? As far as that assumption goes, a value would need to be provided, though how would it be retrieved within this context/what would the VALUES be in the query?

Comment: You would use an insert statement.  Have you read anything on how to insert data into a table using SQL?

Comment: It seems you need to read about basic SQL statements so you can apply that knowledge to your code. I think learning that is the step before programing something that requieres databases.

Comment: Is that C# not aware of Private Sub, doesn't look like C# can you select the right language you are using? Maybe this is what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634516/how-can-i-insert-data-into-sql-server-using-vbnet